# Update a single ListView item

Tags: c#

I have a `ListView` which is loaded like this:

```
ImageList imgList = new ImageList();
textureViewer.LargeImageList = imgList;
textureViewer.LargeImageList.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(50,50);

foreach (Texture t in textureList)
{
     string imgKey = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(t.imageName);
     imgList.Images.Add(imgKey, t.image);

     ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
     item.Text = imgKey;
     item.ImageKey = imgKey;
     textureViewer.Items.Add(item);
}
```

My program let's you change an image whenever you want so I have to update the `ListView` with the new picture you chose. I update it by reusing the code above but I want to be able to update only the selected picture because I don't want to reload and refresh the listview.
How can I do that?

Comment: How do users change the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a tricky question because my way of thinking was just to update the image collection by key in the image list instance and then call `Refresh` of `ListView`... but it doesn't work.

The way that works:

1. Remove the image from the image collection by key.
2. Add a new image with the same key to the image collection.

I assume that you want to update the image using the key

```
Image newImage = ... // new image
string imgKey = ... // the key of the image to update
// find the previous image by key
Image previousImage = imgList.Images[imgList.Images.Keys.IndexOf("imgKey")];
// remove the previous image from the collection
imgList.Images.RemoveByKey(imgKey);
// add a new image
imgList.Images.Add(imgKey, newImage);
// dispose the previous image
previousImage.Dispose();
```

I've added the call to the `Dispose` method.

Comment: Thanks :) that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Tag` property on the `ListViewItem` instance. Set the `Tag` to something meaningful, like `imgKey`. Then, you can find the correct ListViewItem you want to update by iterating over the items and comparing `Tag` to the imgKey you want to update. You can also use LINQ, `textureViewer.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>.Where(i => i.Tag.Equals(match));`

You can use this logic to update multiple items that point to the same Tag.

Just remember to add your new `imgKey` and image to your image list, as well as update the `Tag` property on the `ListViewItem`, otherwise you may get an exception/bug.

If the `imgKey` doesn't change but only the actual image, then all you should have to do is update the image list and `Invalidate` the list view.